# How to rotate Skype incoming video stream?

Tags: software-rec, skype

One of my Skype pal's video webcam which is built into the notebook is somehow trasferring frames upside down. She can't really do much to fix it. Therefore I have to find a way to flip incoming video strem. So the question - is there any software that may let me to flip the incoming video? I know there is a software to flip outgoing frames, but she can't install it, out of question.

Comment: ask her to get the tech service to flip the camera back

Comment: I need solution from my side, please. I know many solutions which can be done from remote side, but none of them are applicable.

Comment: I haven't played with Skype video. Can it be recorded in any standard format? I believe that ffmpeg can rotate/flip video streams and files, but that won't help if Skype is using a proprietary format. If Skype won't give you direct access to the video frames, you'll need to ask them to add this feature.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to get your skype stream on a media player like vlc and then flip the video stream in the media player .
There is an option of specifying to and from PORTs in skype ,check this [link](http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=72601) .
This [tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14751/rotate-a-video-90-degrees-with-vlc-or-windows-live-movie-maker/) explains you how to flip a video on vlc
I hope this helps you although i am not very sure of the results .

Comment: Looks like this port thing is related to voice and requires API usage, haven't found it in settings.